# How do I say "best practice" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

"Best practice" is a way that is generally accepted as the best way to do something, something one can see as the best or ideal way of doing things. It might be a standard that people strive for in an industry.
How would one express that in Esperanto?

Answer (score 6):

My first thought was *plejbonkutime*, but I think *praktiko* ("application, putting into practice") is okay here, and follows the international form.

Little has been written in Esperanto about management, but I would translate as follows.

- *Bonpraktike, oni...* It is [a] good practice to...
- *Plejbonpraktike, oni...* Best practice is to...
- *La konsilinda regulo estas...* The advisable policy is to...
- *Konsilinde estas... Konsilindas...* It is advisable to...
- *Ni sekvas industriajn (plej)bonpraktikojn.* We follow industry best practices.
- *Ĉi tiu metodo estas industria normo.* This method is an industry standard.
- *Konforme al (plej)bonpraktiko en nia industrio...* In conformance with best practice in our industry...